# Message app users to download new version when they open app next

Tags: android

As the heading says. I would like to know how can i do this for my android apps existing users? Like when the start the game next time a small popup says you should download new version which is available now? I am using eclipse to develop this app.
I dont have any server for this app and there is no website. All the data is within the app on android market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Market software on the phone will notify users when new versions become available. Depending on the user's settings, it may even download and install the new version automatically.

Don't waste time trying to implement this yourself. Let the Market handle it.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot check for new versions of your app without internet access. The easiest way is to have an own server, but since you don't have one, there is only one option:

You have to access the market link of your App and filter the source code of this website for the version number.

This is NOT the best way since Google probably will change the source code of the market website for enhancements. So you have to make sure that you keep track of those changes.

One thing is for sure: An app should work even if there is a newer version. It is much better (and less annoying) for the user if he is able to decide wether he wants to use the old version or update. Consider that the user does not want to download the newest version because of the size of the update or other reasons.

Comment: I dont want users to forcefully get the new version. All i want is a single line of text download newer version, when they open the app. Thats it!

Comment: Well, ok. That's possible by accessing the market page. But the point still stands: Don't be too pushy. The user might already know this by a market notification. I guess most users will accept a Toast-message as notification, but a AlertDialog you have to interact with would just be obtrusive.